# Check if the cell to the left and right of selected cell contain Shapes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count consecutive days off for employees and I am using Shapes in cells to display their schedule. I am trying to count if cells to the left or right of the selected one contains a shape with a particular RGB --> then it would count as a consecutive day off. Before using shapes I could use `cell.offset(0,-1).interior.color=rgb(64,64,64)` or `cell.offset(0,1).interior.color` to check for that but with shapes I don't know how to refer to those cells now.

**Here is part of the code.**

```
Sub Consecutive_count()
Dim TotalOff As Long
Dim myrange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim Numfound As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim Mycount As Long
Dim shpOval As Shape

Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("C6:I13")

'looping through shpOvals to count TotalOFF

For Each shpOval In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shpOval.AutoShapeType = msoShapeOval And shpOval.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64) Then
        TotalOff = TotalOff + 1
    End If

'This part isn't working: Need to check if cells around the black shape also contain black shapes

    If shpOval.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64) And (cell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(64, 64, 64) Or cell.Offset(0, -1).Interior.Color = RGB(64, 64, 64)) Then
        Numfound = Numfound + 1

    End If
Next shpOval


If Numfound > 0 Then
    Range("AA9").Value = Format(Numfound / TotalOff, "#.##%")
Else: Range("AA9").Value = "0%"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cell where the top left corner of the shape stands by accessing the `TopLeftCell` method.

So the second condition in you if-statement would look like this:

```
shpOval.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(64, 64, 64)
```

For the third condition, you need to be able to refer to the shape from the cell that is its top left cell. To do that you could use a function like this that loops through all shapes and finds the first that has for top left cell the cell you provide

```
Function TopLeftCellToShape(ByRef MyTopLeftCell As Range) As Shape

    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In MyTopLeftCell.Parent.Shapes
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = MyTopLeftCell.Address Then
            Set TopLeftCellToShape = shp
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Hence, your third condition would be:

```
TopLeftCellToShape(cell.Offset(0, -1)).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64)
```

Comment: That is to access the cell.offset(0,1) but how can I check if that cell contains shpOval.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(64, 64, 64) now?

Comment: @Khrystyna - I've edited my answer to address that part of the question. Please let me know if this works.